# Where can I watch Sailor Moon legally?

Tags: sailor-moon

I want to start watching Sailor Moon but I don't know where to watch it legally. Can anyone tell me where to watch it starting from the very first season?

Answer (score 4):

I found these sites while browsing the net:

### Sailor Moon:

- Hulu: https://www.hulu.com/series/sailor-moon-4e1c9108-f973-48fb-8824-a69280ca0438
- Viz: https://www.viz.com/watch/streaming/sailor-moon (Country Specific)

### Sailor Moon Crystal:

- Bandai Channel: https://www.b-ch.com/ttl/index.php?ttl_c=4233
- Hulu: https://www.hulu.com/series/sailor-moon-crystal-f8ab94ad-27b1-416b-a463-
- Crunchyroll: https://www.crunchyroll.com/sailor-moon-crystal (does not require membership)

I was unable to personally try the sites that are restricted by region or country, so, if you want to see more options, you can browse through [our community curated list of legal online sources.](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-can-i-tell-if-a-site-is-legal)

---

**Sources:**

- Quora: [Is Sailor Moon on Netflix or Hulu?](https://www.quora.com/Is-Sailor-Moon-available-on-Netflix-or-Hulu)
- [Tonepoet](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/32564/tonepoet): (Verified the Viz U.R.L. with [a screenshot](https://postimg.cc/JtmHSbnD))
- [Maroon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2604/maroon) (Mentioned Crunchyroll)

Comment: @Tonepoet Nope. It's not available, for me at least, but no warning message appears that the content is blocked in my country. Only the blu-rays and DVD's are listed there.

Comment: [Here's a screenshot of what I saw at the specified U.R.L. if anybody else wanting to vote can't verify that link for themselves.](https://postimg.cc/JtmHSbnD)

Comment: @Tonepoet Seems like it is only available for some countries. Thanks for verifying!

Comment: SMC is also on Crunchyroll, which might be preferred over Hulu since it doesn't require a membership.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some seasons on Hulu, but I've found in my experience the best place for animes is definitely Crunchyroll. I used to watch Sailor Moon Crystal on Crunchyroll with my mom, and if I remember correctly, it had all the seasons. There's also a few seasons of Sailor Moon Crystal on Netflix.